# Insert image in Uploaded pdf file Laravel 5.5

Tags: pdf, laravel-5

I need to upload a PDF file and insert a generated 2D Barcode in the uploaded file

The 2D Barcode image generation I have that figured out already,

What is the simplest way to add that image to the pdf file using laravel, any help would be much appreciated

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use fpdf:
http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm

For example:

```
// Insert a logo in the top-left corner at 300 dpi
$pdf->Image('logo.png',10,10,-300);
```

Comment: does " fpdf " gives me options to do modifications on uploaded pdf file ?